# Cannot switch between classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I've got a problem with switching between element classes - probably sth stupid, but I couldn't find the answer. 
In my system I display a list of items. Now I want to be able to promote items, so that they appear at the top of the list. I created some backend infrastructure which works ok and added things to my frontend: a star (a span with star bg) next to every item's title and a jQuery script which is supposed to:

1. listen to 'click' event - when I click on a star
2. get some data- attributes from the span
3. post them to my controller
4. the controller checks if I'm allowed to promote items and replies 'true' or 'false'
5. if 'true' then I switch between 'gold-star' and 'silver-star' classes of the item

For some reason the classes don't switch - only when I refresh the page I can see the effect. I tried debugging with Firebug - it gets to the toggle line, but then nothing happens.

Here's the code:

```
<span class="silver-star promote">

 $(".promote").bind("click", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var itemId = $this.attr("data-id"),
            isPromoted = true;

        if ($this.hasClass("gold-star")) {
            isPromoted = false;
        }

        $.post('/promoteitems', { itemId: itemId, isPromoted: isPromoted }, function(allowPromotion) {
            if (allowPromotion == true) {
                $this.toggleClass("silver-star").toggleClass("gold-star");
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't the issue, but there's no point to `if (allowPromotion == true)`. Simply `if (allowPromotion)` is all you need. The `== true` is just redundant.

Comment: The only way I see for the classes not to be toggled is if `allowPromotion` comes back with a value that isn't `== true`. If it does, it's not like `toggleClass` doesn't work. So set a breakpoint on the `if` and look at the value you're getting back for `allowPromotion`.

Comment: Another tip: `$this.toggleClass("silver-star gold-star")` is equivalent to `$this.toggleClass("silver-star").toggleClass("gold-star")` (jQuery checks and toggles them individually).

Comment: I think he mentioned that he has set a breakpoint where he toggles and it does get there.
Also can you inspect the element once it runs the code, that whether the element has that class or not. It might be a css issue. 
Between thanks, for the tip, didn't know that. They need to have like button on comments :/

Comment: @JRulle, yep he is right, didn't notice the $this. any operation which is asynchronous like timeout or an ajax call will have window as the object in focus

Comment: @JRulle: No, `$this` is a variable. You're thinking of `this`.

Comment: @JRulle: No, the execution context for the call to `click` survives beyond the `click` handler function returning, because the ajax success function created within the context has a reference to it. This is how JavaScript's closures work: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html Thus, the ajax success function continues to have access to the `$this` variable (through the context's *binding object*).

Comment: Hi, I've made the little adjustments that @T.J.Crowder suggested - I removed '== true' and combined the toggle... and it works! I think that the reason it wasn't working may be the '== true' in the end: the allowPromotion value is 'True' (with a capital T), so it's not exactly equal to 'true', but on the other hand, Firebug's debugger did hit the breakpoint inside the 'if' statement... this is confusing, but I'm glad it works now :) Thanks a lot for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting a response back it might not recognise it as a boolean simple test would be to check response as string

Comment: If (allowPromotiom =  "true")... u might want to check the casing also

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the question:

> ...the allowPromotion value is 'True' (with a capital T)...

That tell us it's a string, not a boolean. You **don't** want to just do `if (allowPromotion)`, because that will toggle the classes even if you get back `"False"`.

Instead:

```
if (allowPromotion == "True") { // Note the quotes and capital T
    // ...toggle the classes
}
```

Or if you want to allow for possibly getting back something with a lower-case T at some point in the future:

```
if (/^\s*true\s*$/i.test(allowPromotion)) {
    // ...toggle the classes
}
```

That's over-engineering it a bit (it'll work with `"True"`, `"true"`, `" True "` [note the spaces], and even an actual boolean `true`)...